# Can we use multiple manifests for Android's repo tool? Can we include multiple manifests in a single manifest?

Tags: repo

I have a collection of git projects, which are part of multiple different (super)projects. I am looking for a nice hierarchical way of representing this through manifests. No git submodules please are being used.

I want to organize them hierarchically, so that we don't have duplication of manifest entries. Is this possible with repo and how can it be done. Any documentation or examples on this would be helpful.